# How to get rid of default_intent in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

Following is the response for my simple application. I expected it to have an intent as open_screen but it shows the intent as default_intent. where did I made the error.

```
{  
   "entities":{  
   "screen_name":[  
     {  
        "confidence":0.9928150760384576,
        "start":10,
        "end":27,
        "body":"inventory console",
        "value":{  
           "value":"inventory console"
        },
        "entity":"screen_name"
     }
  ]
},
"confidence":null,
"_text":"lets open inventory console",
"intent": "default_intent",
"intent_id": "57bb1f3b-3098-4a17-a0d1-8d41e0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing. Do you have a new app (with Stories) or an old app? In the new apps, intent are now trait entities. This is why you may see a "default_intent", but if you use the latest version of the app, it should disappear.